# Peltier fridge and heat sink

Tags: peltier

Iam trying to make a mini refrigerator with peltier device. I do have two heat sinks and the hot side of the device is connected to a fan. The colder side is connted to another heat sink with thermal paste and some adhesive. The question is how can i spread the temperature from the cold side to my componet?

Answer (score 1):

Attach the cold side to a metal plate aluminium or copper for example and use heat transfer paste to improve the contact.